# Tensorflow: Memory error when building graphs in a loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to modify an existing model and test the prediction. Therefore, I build a graph, test it and then I build the next graph. I do this in a for loop. In more detail, in `get_new_graph()` I load a pre-trained VGG16 model where I add a single layer to the network. Depending on which `test` I choose, the size of the last layer varies.

```
import vgg
slim = tf.contrib.slim

def experiment():
    for test in tests:
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        X, new_pred = get_new_graph(test) # load VGG16 model + add layer
        variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore()
        saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            saver.restore(sess, './vgg16.ckpt')
            for k in range(100):
                R = sess.run(new_pred, feed_dict={X:images})
                print(R)
            sess.close()
```

When I run this code, I am able to do three tests with 1000 images from imagenet. Then I get a memory error since the GPU memory is full:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:267]
Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to 
allocate 64.00MiB.  Current allocation summary follows.
```

How do I have to modify my code to make it run?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17048

Comment: @Tezirg Can you please be more specific. I'm not sure which of all these answers can solve my problem. I tried `cuda.select_device(0); cuda.close()` which results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: You just chose the worst answer in the whole issue.. Maybe read everything, or if you want to try copy paste random code, maybe start with the most upvoted answer by `nathandouglas`

Comment: @Tezirg I don't understand the solution from `nathandouglas`. How would my code look like if I would use the answer by `nathandouglas`?

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in this issue on TensorFlow's github: 
http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17048

It seems possible to create each session in a different process, so that it releases the gpu when the process terminates.

It could look something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def _process(X, new_pred, images):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, './vgg16.ckpt')
        for k in range(100):
            R = sess.run(new_pred, feed_dict={X:images})
            print(R)
        sess.close()


def experiment():
    for test in tests:
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        X, new_pred = get_new_graph(test) # load VGG16 model + add layer
        variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore()
        saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
        with Pool(1) as p:
            return p.apply(_process, (X, new_pred, images,))
```

Comment: Using this approach I am getting the following error message `TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects`. Any ideas how to solve that issue?